# Scrape tab href value from a webpage by python Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have code that extracts links from the main page and navigates through each page in the list of links, the new link has a tab page that is represented as follows in the source:

```
 <Li Class=" tab-contacts" Id="contacts"><A Href="?id=448&tab=contacts"><Span Class="text">Contacts</Span>
```

I want to extract the href value and navigate to that page to get some information, here is my code so far:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get(link_to_the_website)
data = r.content  
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
links = []

for i in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'leftInfoWrap'}):
    link = i.find('a',href=True)
    if link is None:
        continue
    links.append(link.get('href'))

for link in links:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(link,"lxml")
    tabs = soup.select('Li',{'class':'  tab-contacts'})
    print(tabs)
```

However I am getting an empty list with 'print(tabs)' command. I did verify the link variable and it is being populated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your indentation is rather messy. I guess the issue is that links.append is indented and placed under continue, it will never populate the list that way. I suggest making it an if-else statement.

Comment: My bad, I added the snippets of codes by themselves in this area, I can edit them thanks!

Comment: I see you edited them, thanks a lot!

Comment: I did try the space before the tab in the tab contacts and the 'Li' is the markup used in the source code of the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to mix `find` syntax with `select`.

I would use the parent id as an anchor then navigate to the child with css selectors and child combinator.

```
partial_link = soup.select_one('#contacts > a')['href']
```

You need to append the appropriate prefix.